# How to get a path of the app bundle in a CMake script to supply it to the fixup_bundle()?

Tags: macos, qt, cmake, bundle

I have a cross-platform application for the Win and Mac OSX platforms written in C++, Qt and a little bit of Objective C. After a period of supporting two unrelated platform specific projects (VS 2010 and xCode) we decided to create a single CMake script. We generate a platform specific project and work with it.

After a pretty long delving I have managed to compile and link my application. But there are still plenty problems with creating a proper bundle (without any efforts xCode just creates a binary). After setting a few variables xCode compiles and creates a dummy bundle without a plist file and app's executable. So I need to copy all required frameworks and resources to the bundle.

I've tried a few approaches to create a bundle. The first one was to use `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES( ${resourcePath} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION ${pathInsideBundle} )` and adding them (frameworks\resources) to ADD_EXECUTABLE like this: `ADD_EXECUTABLE( FranchiseTracker MACOSX_BUNDLE ${headers} ${sources} ${form_headers} ${resources_rcc} ${thirdparty_sources} ${BUNDLE_COPY_RESOURCES} )`. And it worked out - I've managed to copy an icon and the Sparkle framework to the bundle, but the problem was that I couldn't copy the Qt frameworks, because `FIND_PACKAGE` left the `${QT_LIBRARIES}` variable empty, so I couldn't get the paths to copy frameworks "manually".

Now I'm gonna use the "fix_bundle" approach because it promises me to copy all required resources without my intervention. So, here is my code related to fixup_bundle():

```
# Fixup bundle, copy dynamic libraries into app bundle
SET( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/out )
SET( APPS "\${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/out/${APP_NAME}.app" ) # paths to executables
SET( DIRS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/osx/FRP/vendors/libraries/lib" ) # directories to search for prerequisites
INSTALL( CODE "
    include(BundleUtilities)
    fixup_bundle(\"${APPS}\" \"\" \"${DIRS}\")
")
```

Now I'm stumped by a little refinement. The thing is stubborn xCode persists to generate and write my bundle in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/out/Debug` and thus fixup_bundle can't find any bundle at all.

**My specific question** (as in the title): How can I get the correct path (with Debug) in the CMake script? I wanna avoid to hardcode the path with Debug, because that will be wrong in a case of archiving.

**My more common question**: Is there an easier way of creating bundles for a Qt application with CMake? Maybe the whole my approach is wrong?

**P.S.** I have posted the full script to Code Review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18706/how-to-do-this-cmake-script-in-a-right-way).

**P.P.S.** For those who will consider my question as too verbose. The reason I've posted the full script and written my attempts (except I want to get it working) is that there is little info on the internet about working with Mac OSX frameworks, bundles, etc in CMake. I had to read a lot of mailing lists because I couldn't find any structured tutorials or at least a decent documentation. And the only source to learn were other scripts written by other people. So I hope my script and explanations will help someone.

Comment: I completely agree with the lack of good examples and information in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finished with using only the `macdeployqt` utility on the Mac OSX platform. I use xCode to build my application, so I've solved the path issue with xCode's macros `${CONFIGURATION}` like that:

```
....
elseif( APPLE )
    ADD_EXECUTABLE( FranchiseTracker MACOSX_BUNDLE ${headers} ${sources} ${form_headers} ${resources_rcc} ${thirdparty_sources} ${BUNDLE_COPY_RESOURCES} )
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( FranchiseTracker PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${APP_NAME} )
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( FranchiseTracker PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/osx/FRP/info.plist") #or else you'll get an auto generated plist

    # Fixup bundle, copy dynamic libraries into app bundle
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND( TARGET FranchiseTracker COMMAND macdeployqt ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/\${CONFIGURATION}/${APP_NAME}.app ) # add -dmg for an image
endif( WIN32 )
```

Pay attention to escaping the $ character to prevent `${CONFIGURATION}` from being expanded as a CMake variable.

**P.S.** The code I've posted to CodeReview is a little bit outdated, so if anybody stumbles the same issue (with creating a bundle on OSX) and wants to see the full working variant, just let me know and I'll post it somewhere (maybe update my post on CodeReview).

Comment: I’d be interested actually in seeing the updated example code, if the offer still stands

Comment: @fish2000 oh, I've changed my employer companies several times since the post, so unfortunately I can't get the script anymore, sorry :( But I hope my approach in the answer will help you anyway